# How to solve ApkProvisionException when build android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have build one project in android studio and i'm getting ApkprovisionException. If i build normal apk and install using terminal then its working fine.

My error is Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: Couldn't get post build model. Module: amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-android.main Variant: minSdk24Debug.

I have to researched about error and tried to again all gradle sync, Invalid caches and restart. but currently error is not resolved.